# Websocket messages mysteriously disappear

Tags: windows, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I'm going crazy trying to figure out what's wrong with my system that it is unable to send websocket messages. I've tried a ton of things:

- Chrome 32, firefox 27, ie 10
- various websocket server libraries: ws, websocket, nodejs-websocket
- running the server on windows and centos
- reinstalling node.js (to version 0.10.26)
- reinstalling firefox
- Turning off my firewall

The behavior is always the same: both client and server say they get a connection, but when the client tries to send a message, the other one simply doesn't get it. Sometimes i get "Error: read ECONNRESET" on the server - but not all the time. About 50% of the time it just fails silently. Eventually the connection closes.

If I add code to send a message from the server on connection, it always gets "Error: read ECONNRESET".

What does work?

- the exact same code and setup on my laptop
- any websocket code online, for example this: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

So what could cause *just* my local websocket connection to silently drop messages?

Server:

var

```
 ws = require('websocket').server
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("connection received for "+request.url)
    response.writeHead(404)
    response.end()  
})
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("now listening")    
})

wsServer = new ws({httpServer:server, autoAcceptConnections: false})

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log("got request")
    var connection = request.accept('a', request.origin)
    console.log("got connection")
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log("got message: "+message)
    })      

    connection.on("close", function() {
        console.log("closed")   
    })

    connection.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error: '+e)    
    })
})
```

Output:

`got connection
closed`

Client:

```
<script>    
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'a')
ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('open') 
    ws.send('something2')
}

ws.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e)  
}

ws.onmessage = function(m) {
    console.log(m)
}       

ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log('closed')   
}
</script>
```

Output

`open
closed`

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Update: I finally debugged through this stuff down into net.js where the error was happening. An "errnoException" was being created because the buffer was undefined and the socket had an EOF - which is mysterious. But the real mystery was that after one or two runs debugging through, the connection was suddenly fine. All the run through's after that had no errors. I shut down the debugger and ran the server alone - its worked fine thereafter. I still have absolutely no idea what could have happened.

Comment: Another update: its happening again. I've tried a python websocket server with similar results as well now.