# WebSockets with node.js - "garbage" in packet capture and socket resets

Tags: windows, node.js, network-programming, websocket, network-protocols

I've been having lots of problems getting websockets to work recently. I know how to use them and I've used them successfully before, but things that should by all rights work, aren't working. I'm on windows 7 using node.js v0.10.26 . I've tried various things (see here [Websocket messages mysteriously disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369636/websocket-messages-mysteriously-disappear)), but right now I just want to focus on the server I'm creating with 'websocket' (https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node). Here is the server:

```
var ws = require('websocket').server
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("connection received for "+request.url)
    response.writeHead(404)
    response.end()  
})
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("now listening")    
})

wsServer = new ws({httpServer:server, autoAcceptConnections: false})

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log("got request")
    var connection = request.accept('a', request.origin)
    console.log("got connection")

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log("got message: "+message)
    })      

    connection.on("close", function() {
        console.log("closed")   
    })

    connection.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error: '+ e.stack)
    })
})
```

And the client:

```
var ws = require('websocket').client

client = new ws

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket client connected')

    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        } else {
            console.log("Received: '" + message + "'");
        }
    });

    connection.sendUTF("test sending");
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'a');
```

Server output:

```
now listening
got request
got connection
Error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)
closed
```

Client output:

```
WebSocket client connected
Connection Closed
```

Rawcap output:

```
¡²ÃÔ            ÿÿ   eS:Üm 
’Ø   4   4E  4â@ €      Ášáª    €  J4  ÿ×S:Üm 
–À   4   4E  4ã@ €      Áš÷“Sá«€  ¿¾  ÿ×S:Üm 
–À   (   (E  (ä@ €      Ášá«÷“TP  –  S:Üm 
ªH   Ü   ÜE  Üå@ €      Ášá«÷“TP  ±   GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6ilNFU9aUzOnlvL8+QUcVQ==
Host: localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: a

S:Üm 
ªH   (   (E  (æ@ €      Áš÷“Tá_P ã  S:Üm 
É‰   Ä   ÄE  Äç@ €      Áš÷“Tá_P }  HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: cgLNQgJeCA0LXM2p8Mw2TMVq8Pc=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: a

S:Üm 
É‰   (   (E  (è@ €      Ášá_÷“ðP G  S:Üm 
àù   (   (E  (é@ €      Ášá_÷“ñP F  S:Üm 
àù   (   (E  (ê@ €      Ášá_÷“ñP E  S:Üm 
äá   (   (E  (ë@ €      Ášá`÷“ñP  `  S:Üm 
äá   (   (E  (ì@ €      Áš÷“ðá_P G  S:Üm 
äá   (   (E  (í@ €      Ášá_á_P  x3
```

I didn't always get an "ECONNRESET" error - it seems to only *sometimes* happen. Other times there was about 15 to 20 seconds of nothing happening between when it connected and when it closed. The rawcap output looks really suspicious to me - there's a lot of stuff in there that looks like garbage. The only other traffic i've seen on my loopback interface is some upnp stuff, but that garbage doesn't look related to upnp.

I also tried this with a browser websocket session on chrome 33.0.1750.149 m with the client:

```
<script>

var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'a')
ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket client connected')   
    ws.send('testing')
}

ws.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e)  
}

ws.onmessage = function(m) {
    console.log(m.data)
}   

ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log('Connection Closed')   
}

</script>
```

This had exactly the same output for client and server.

Rawcap output for the browser session:

```
¡²ÃÔ            ÿÿ   eS:Üô 
¡b   4   4E  46@ €      ÁÇ€`gæ    €  K  ÿ×S:Üô 
©2   4   4E  47@ €      ÁÇÁK:˜€`gç€  ‘V  ÿ×S:Üô 
­   (   (E  (8@ €      ÁÇ€`gçÁK:™P  ì-  S:Üô 
´ê  î  îE î9@ €      ÁÇ€`gçÁK:™P  v»  GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: a
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: BkPvYoibS9i+g79JBOnVFQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36

S:Üô 
´ê   (   (E  (:@ €      ÁÇÁK:™€`i­P êi  S:Üô c   Ò   ÒE  Ò;@ €      ÁÇÁK:™€`i­P [  HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: hXGSMoUCji4jazy7i4z/FlQ+utk=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: a
Origin: null

S:Üô c   (   (E  (<@ €      ÁÇ€`i­ÁK;CP é¾  S:Üô *   (   (E  (=@ €      ÁÇ€`i­ÁK;DP é½  S:Üô *   (   (E  (>@ €      ÁÇ€`i­ÁK;DP é¼  S:Üô *   (   (E  (?@ €      ÁÇ€`i®ÁK;DP  é×  S:Üô *   (   (E  (@@ €      ÁÇÁK;C€`i­P é¿  S:Üô *   (   (E  (A@ €      ÁÇ€`i­€`i­P  üj
```

Does anyone have any idea if the rawcap output indicates something wrong with my machine or installations of something? Does the rawcap output look right? Has anyone seen anything like this before? Note that the node.js client to node.js server works fine in my centos vagrant instance on this same machine.